# Modal NSAlert within block not displayed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, block, nsalert

In my document-based application, I have overridden the method openDocument: in my subclass of NSDocumentcontroller so that I can display my own openPanel. I pass the chosen URLs to the method openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:. I use this code for the call:

```
[self openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:[chosenFiles objectAtIndex:i] display:YES completionHandler:^(NSDocument *document, BOOL documentWasAlreadyOpen, NSError *error) {

    if (document == nil)
    {
        NSAlert* alert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
        [alert runModal];
    }

}];
```

So I want to display the passed error if nil gets returned as a reference to the document. The problem is, that the program just "freezes" after I press the "Open" button in the open panel. Then I need to manually stop the program with the "stop" button in Xcode. No spinning beach ball appears, though. If I comment the line "[alert runModal]", the program does not freeze any more, but no alert is displayed, of course.

Now the strange thing: The code works *sometimes*. If I switch from Xcode to my browser and back and I run the program again, it sometimes works flawlessly and the error is displayed. After some time it stops working again. It is unpredictable, but most of the time it doesn't work.

All this sounds like a race-condition to me. It certainly has something to do with the block? But what do I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe runModel on the main thread. [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runModel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: dont you want to use [alert show]?

Comment: @mark: Thank you, this seems to have fixed it. As the error was quite unpredictable, I'm not completely sure yet. Why was it necessary to explicitly execute it on the main thread?

Comment: @Kyle: NSAlert has no member function "show". I guessed that "runModal" is the only possibility to display it if one has no window yet.

Comment: @Kyle Tungsten is right, I believe you're thinking of iOS's `show` for `UIAlertView`, on OS X you use `runModal` to display an `NSAlert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

runModel on the main thread.

```
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runModal) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I think runModel needs to be called on the main thread because it's part of the AppKit framework, and it's estentially triggering UI graphics. I believe all calls to the AppKit framework or to any method that manipulates graphics needs to be on the main thread.

Comment: How can we get return valueof Runmodal. As according to the return value of button pressed, further cation has to be take place. Please comment on this